# Android studio emulator is not running my app when I click run

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I could include code for this problem but I don't think it will help solve the problem due to it being in the emulator and I've tried this on different projects with the same issue. I have tried multiple things such as resetting cache, cleaning build, using another emulator, running the app once I have emulator up and running, cold booting, wiping data on emulator, and nothing seems to work. I have looked at 10+ links on this topic and none seem to help. Any tips would be great, thank you.

Comment: Did you app install successfully in you emulator? Any log in logcat?

Comment: No, I also just now tried on two different physical devices with no luck, my logcat is infinite. Also what's weird is when I click the x to terminate my emulator and click 'no' I don't want to save the previous state etc it saves the state

Comment: So the log-cat says my emulator is disconnected. Any advice?

Comment: Could you try run `cd <your project> && ./gradlew installDebug`. If any errors show up, please pass it here

Answer (score 0):

I tried turning off instant run but I don't have that anymore. I could reset android studio back to factory But then again is it even worth it if the issue will come up again?